# error mysql query with inner join

Tags: mysql

```
select simplex_comunes.cod_color_piel.descripcion as cod_color_piel, simplex_comunes.cod_sexo.descripcion as cod_sexo, count(*)
from simplex_comunes.cod_color_piel,simplex_comunes.cod_sexo
inner join simplex_ch.dat_trabajadores on simplex_ch.dat_trabajadores.id_color_piel = simplex_comunes.cod_color_piel.codigo
inner join simplex_ch.dat_trabajadores on simplex_comunes.cod_sexo.codigo = simplex_ch.dat_trabajadores.id_sexo
group by simplex_comunes.cod_color_piel.descripcion,simplex_comunes.cod_sexo.descripcion
```

the error is Not unique table/alias: 'dat_trabajadores',

Please help, thanks!!!

Comment: You are joining `dat_trabajadores` twice.  You need to give one (or both) an alias, so that it can tell them apart.

Comment: When you ask a question like this you need to provide your table structure also. It's really hard to debug a query without that.

Comment: 'cod_sexo', 'CREATE TABLE `cod_sexo` (
  `codigo` smallint(2) NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` varchar(20) default NULL,
  `siglas` varchar(10) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`codigo`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'

Comment: 'cod_color_piel', 'CREATE TABLE `cod_color_piel` (
  `codigo` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` varchar(15) default NULL,
  `siglas` varchar(10) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`codigo`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'

Comment: 'dat_trabajadores', 'CREATE TABLE `dat_trabajadores` (
  `consecutivo` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `nro_identidad` varchar(11) NOT NULL default '',
  `nro_tarjeta` varchar(11) default NULL,
  `id_sexo` smallint(2) unsigned default '0',
  `id_color_piel` smallint(3) unsigned default '0',
  ......

  PRIMARY KEY  (`consecutivo`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=10540 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked if your query is "intelligent" or not, but you have to use `aliases` as you use twice `dat_trabajadores` in your query.

You have to tell MySQL which table you use in your `JOIN`.

```
select simplex_comunes.cod_color_piel.descripcion as cod_color_piel, simplex_comunes.cod_sexo.descripcion as cod_sexo, count(*)
from simplex_comunes.cod_color_piel,simplex_comunes.cod_sexo
inner join simplex_ch.dat_trabajadores tr1 on simplex_ch.tr1.id_color_piel = simplex_comunes.cod_color_piel.codigo
inner join simplex_ch.dat_trabajadores tr2 on simplex_comunes.cod_sexo.codigo = simplex_ch.tr2.id_sexo
group by simplex_comunes.cod_color_piel.descripcion,simplex_comunes.cod_sexo.descripcion
```

Comment: When I try to use this way, I get this error, Unknown column 'simplex_comunes.cod_color_piel.codigo' in 'on clause', and I still without understand, simplex_comunes.cod_color_piel is in the from clause, and have 'codigo' column.

Answer (score 0):

you have two same aliases in your query.

rename them differently

```
select simplex_comunes.cod_color_piel.descripcion as descripcion, 
  simplex_comunes.cod_sexo.descripcion as cod_sexo_descripcion, 
 count(*)
from simplex_comunes.cod_color_piel,simplex_comunes.cod_sexo
inner join simplex_ch.dat_trabajadores t1 on t1.id_color_piel = simplex_comunes.cod_color_piel.codigo
inner join simplex_ch.dat_trabajadores t2 on simplex_comunes.cod_sexo.codigo =  t2.id_sexo
group by  simplex_comunes.cod_color_piel.descripcion,simplex_comunes.cod_sexo.descripcion
```

Comment: When I try to use this way, I get this error, Unknown column 'simplex_comunes.cod_color_piel.codigo' in 'on clause', and I still without understand, simplex_comunes.cod_color_piel is in the from clause, and have 'codigo' column